# Updating GTK window and adding new image with every iteration of a loop

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk3

I am trying to add images to a window using gtk, I run through a while loop over a matrix that each one has certain value and I want to add a new image to the location on the screen every time I get a match.

currently I am getting the final window opens at the end of the function and what I am expecting to get is that the pictures will load one by one in every iteration of the while loop with a delay of 1.

This is my very first experience with gtk so I would appreciate any help and advice.

```c
void ShowMatrix(int solution[SIZE_ROW][SIZE_COL]) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *image;
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    int print_mat[SIZE_ROW][SIZE_COL];
    int i, j;
    int counter = 1;
    

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Pooing Dog");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    

    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);
 

    while (counter <= 64)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE_ROW; i++) 
        {
            for (j = 0; j < SIZE_COL; j++) 
            {
                if (solution[i][j] == counter) 
                {
                    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("Negev_t.png", NULL);
                    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
                    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), image, j, i, 1, 1);
                    gtk_widget_show(image);
                    gtk_widget_queue_draw(window);
                    gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);
                    sleep(1);

                }
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    gtk_main();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what your question here is actually?